# Problema al subir archivos a repositorio github

Tags: git, github

al momento de cargar los archivos al repositorio no me deja y me sale ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fijate que tu push..esta apuntando a "pruebas"...y deberia ser almacen..primero debes agregar los cambios con "git add ." luego un mensaje con "git commit -m 'test' " luego agregas tu codigo a github "git push -f origin master"

Comment: bien, ese era el problema, gracias

Comment: Por favor, los mensajes, código, etc, han de colocarse **como texto**, no como imágenes. Ningún buscador interpreta imágenes, por lo que ningún futuro usuario con tu problema encontrará esta publicación.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es recomendable realizar `git pull` antes de subir cambios para bajar los posibles cambios en tu repositorio remoto y fusionarlos con tus cambios locales

ejemplo:

//agrega los archivos que haz modificado localmente

> git add .

o agregar solo un archivo

> git add fileName.txt

//realizas un commit con su respectivo comentario

> git commit -m "comentarios acerca de los cambios que realizaste"

// por si existen cambios en el repositorio remoto

> git pull origin master

//para subir los cambios una vez fusionados los cambios

> git push origin master